# $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-x^2}f(x)dx$, prove that there exists $\xi\in(0,\,1)$ such that $f'(\xi)=2\xi f(\xi)$.

Tags: analysis

> $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\,1]$, differentiable on $(0,\,1)$, and satisfies
>   $$
> f(1)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-x^2}f(x)dx.
> $$
>   Prove that there exists $\xi\in(0,\,1)$ such that $f'(\xi)=2\xi f(\xi)$.

Let $F(x)=e^{1-x^2}f(x)$, then it's equivalent to prove that $F(\xi)'=0$.
Also, we have $F(1)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}F(x)\,dx$. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I wonder if it should be $f(1)= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-x^2}f(x)dx$, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335834/42969 for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a mistype.  The correct equation is $ f(1)=2\int_0^{1/2} e^{1-x^{2}}f(x)\, dx$.  I will answer the question with this correction. I would like to thank  Martin R for suggesting this correction.

Suppose $F'$ does not vanish at any point.  Then $F'(x) >0$ for all $x$ or $F'(x) <0$ for all $x$. This is because any derivative has IVP. In the first case $F$ is strictly increasing so $2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} F(x)\, dx < 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} F(1)\, dx =F(1)$, a contradiction. Similarly in the second case we get $ 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} F(x)\, dx > 2 \int_0^{\frac 1 2} F(1)\, dx =F(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong, a counterexample is $F(x) = 1-\frac 67 x$.
$$
F(1)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}F(x)\,dx = \frac 17 \, ,
$$
but $F'$ is nowhere zero.

If you actually meant the equation
$$
f(1)= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{1-x^2}f(x)dx
$$
then the conclusion follows from the mean-value theorem for integrals, as demonstrated in [Rolle's Theorem related exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2335834/42969).